# Solr how to unite filter query

Tags: solr

I want to make solr unite my filters results instead of nesting it.
For instance if I start techproducts example, and add 2 filter query(fq) (cat:connector, cat:music) it founds nothing, but each of this cat has many docs. How can I make solr to search in both of this cat and unite results, can I achive that?

Comment: Right after I ask it, I found solution and it's simple: fq=cat:"music", "connector"

Comment: You can pass more than one fq parameter and they will be both used via an AND operator: `fq=cat:"music"&fq=cat:"connector"` (I am not sure the way you are doing it is correct ` fq=cat:"music", "connector"`)

Comment: @HectorCorrea, you suggest query like that: 127.0.0.1:8983/solr/techproducts/select?fq=cat:%22music%22&fq=cat:%22connector%22&q=*%3A* - but it's found nothing, when 127.0.0.1:8983/solr/techproducts/select?fq=cat:%22music%22,%22connector%22&q=*%3A* gets results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my first comment, this solution works well for me.

> fq=cat:"music", "connector"

or example based on techproducts

> 127.0.0.1:8983/solr/techproducts/select?fq=cat:%22music%22,%22connector%22&q=*%3A*